# Stansted (London) airport needs transit visa for Indian Citizen?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, transit, indian-citizens

I am Indian citizen, and flying thru Stansted (London) with 3 hour layover, flying to the US.

Does this require transit visa?

Comment: The question is not duplicate in the sense different nationalities have different visa requirements. I found pdf from UK gov website : https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/527411/UK_Visa_requirements_3_June_2016.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a valid US visa and are flying there, [you do **not** need a visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/yes)

At the UK border, present your passport (open at the page with the visa), filled-out landing card and connecting ticket.